# Is there an effective way to write to your squad/platoon

Tags: planetside-2

To write a message to your squad/platoon you currently have to type platoonSay/squadSay,
but is there a hotkey or something to do it faster?

Comment: You could always use AutoHotkey to make a script to enter that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/ps for platoon

/sq for squad

Source: http://wiki.planetside-universe.com/ps/Slash_Commands

Comment: Even shorter: /p = platoon, /s = squad. You might also want to add that you can press Alt and click the tab on the top left to always chat in that channel (though messages in other channels aren't visible then)

Comment: You can also use /g (short for 'group') to talk to the squad.